# elastic search interpreter of zeppelin does not work

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Elasticsearch 5.1.1
Zeppelin 0.6.2

Notebook command

```
%elasticsearch

get /tweeter/tweet/1
```

Result message

> Error : None of the configured nodes are available:
>   [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}]

elastic search interpreter setting`enter code here`

```
Default setting
```

`elasticsearch.yml` Setting

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.port: 9200
transport.tcp.port: 9300
```

Answer (score 2):

Zeppelin currently doesnt support ES 5.0. There is a PR for that working in progress but stuck due to many API changes.

https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/1598

---

**Updated**: Recently the PR for adding elastic http client was merged. So now you can use ES 5.0+ in zeppelin using elastic interpreter (http client setting, port 9200)

See also: https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/commit/e763b3bf3e8a26a2e2134bc615aac1bff59cd82d

Comment: Thanks for your answer.